# ess R startup warning locale

Tags: spacemacs, start-up, ess, r

I am using Emacs 25.1.1 with spacemacs. Everytime I run iESS, I get the warning about locale as,

```
During startup - Warning messages:
1: Setting LC_CTYPE failed, using "C" 
2: Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C" 
3: Setting LC_TIME failed, using "C" 
4: Setting LC_MESSAGES failed, using "C" 
5: Setting LC_MONETARY failed, using "C"
```

I have tried the solution from followings,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264526/why-does-my-ess-r-session-fall-back-to-c-locale

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689104/installing-r-on-mac-warning-messages-setting-lc-ctype-failed-using-c

But the problem is still there. The strange this about this problem is that, when I run emacs with `-nw` switch (on terminal) I get no error, but when I open it with frame, I get the error.

Please help me with this!

My R session info when I run emacs with frame is,

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.3.2 tools_3.3.2
```

and in terminal without frame is,

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.2

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.3.2 tools_3.3.2
```

Comment: You posted the same question on StackOverflow. Please do not do that - choose one or the other site. Please delete one of the duplicate questions.

Comment: When you run "emacs -nw", do you use the old Emacs 22 (which comes bundled with macOS), or do you explicitly start Emacs 25? What is the content of `process-environment`, does it differ in any way from the default environment in a terminal?

Comment: No, they both are same version. I have solved this problem by setting up Environment variable for emacs shell from init file. 
`  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "LC_ALL")
  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "LANG")`. Any way thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

For other persons who are having the same problem, I just want to answer my own question. I solved this issue by setting copying the shell environment to emacs as,

```
(exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "LC_ALL")
(exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "LANG")
```

Thank you, everyone, for your help. I got my answer from https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2015-October/011701.html.